# Unable to update php.ini after downloading version from liip.ch [ Error writing php.ini: Permission denied ]

Tags: php, macos

I am attempting to set up PHP on my OSX machine so I can learn PHP and MySql. I have enabled PHP on my machine and had version 5.6 (came with system) and have run my_phpinfo.php and it looks fine.

I am attempting to download the latest version of PHP from because I heard it was the easiest:  https://php-osx.liip.ch/

I have tried running these three versions:

PHP 7.1 (Current stable) - 10.10 and later

PHP 7.0 (Old stable) - 10.10 and later

PHP 5.6 (Old stable) - 10.8 and later

Upon completion of the install, using nano I open php.ini to change certain settings like error_reporting and timezone. When I exit and try to save it give me this error message: 
[ Error writing php.ini: Permission denied ]

When I attempt to change permissions, I get these messages:
[]cipriano@Ciprianos-MacBook-Pro-3 /usr/local/php5/lib -> chmod drwxr-xr-x "php.ini"
chmod: Invalid file mode: drwxr-xr-x
[]cipriano@Ciprianos-MacBook-Pro-3 /usr/local/php5/lib -> chmod drwxr-xr-x php.ini
chmod: Invalid file mode: drwxr-xr-x
[]cipriano@Ciprianos-MacBook-Pro-3 /usr/local/php5/lib -> chmod 755 php.ini
chmod: Unable to change file mode on php.ini: Operation not permitted

Current permission to file:
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel    72K May 25 19:48 php.ini

I am new to using terminal.

What am I doing wrong? What is causing the permission issue?

Should I be at a specific folder when I run the download script from liip?

Should I be changing permission at a higher level (folder level)? Since this is a permission issue for one file, would other permission issue come up when I start running things.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `sudo chmod 755 php.ini`. Runs the command as a superuser. You will be asked for an admin password.

Answer (score 0):

From what I am seeing, you need to run the command as root. That is because you are not the owner of `php.ini` so you don't have permission to change the ownership​.

To run a command as root, you need to type `sudo` before the command. This stands for "SuperUser DO".

I see that you are trying to make the `php.ini` file belong to your user, but that's not such a good idea security wise.

It's better to instead of making it yours, just run nano as root.

So do this to navigate to your php folder:

```
cd /usr/local/php5/lib
```

Then do this to open nano as root:

```
sudo nano php.ini
```

Comment: Thank you Abraham. It worked! Yes, I forgot about the all powerful sudo command. Thanks again. Stack Overflow is great.